# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/central/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 306

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 306

Backtrace:

Answer (score 2):

you can set this in your php file

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

or

```
1. edit php.ini file
2. Find this line: max_execution_time
3. Change its value to 300:
4. max_execution_time = 300;
```

300/60 = 5 minutes will excute

for xampp server need to edit this

```
xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php
```

search

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']
```

then change it

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600; // set higher value

if you do not find this file then
1. go to xampp\phpMyAdmin\ 
2. config.inc.php 
3. Search for $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;
4. update this 300 value higher // 0 unlimited
5. save the file and restart the server
```

Comment: i;m in server not local

Comment: then need to configure this file if you have access or set root file

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);